# Delete completed workflow after workflow completed

Tags: survey-list, designer-workflow

I have a workflow (created in SharePoint Designer)  that notifies users when a survey is completed.

The survey settings are that responses are anonymous and users may only see their own responses. (because of this setting, am uanble setup alerts and therefore use a workflow for notification)

The workflow notifies the Survey Administrators when its completed.
The completed workflows keeps a history of who initiated the workflow and therefore defeats the purpose of anonymous survey.

The example on the [this site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4839.how-to-delete-completed-workflow-instances-in-sharepoint-2007-and-sharepoint-2010-lists-en-us.aspx/), shows how to Delete Completed Workflow.

So to sum up.
After the workflow has performed the notification, it must Delete the Completed Workflow instances from the list.

The current list workflow is as follows:

If Current Item:Completed equals 1
   Email SurveyAdmin

Comment: So you mean Submission -> notify workflow - then delete the current item?

Comment: Hi @PirateEric 
Correct, to clarify "delete the current item" will be the information for the Completed Workflow